# Debugging function that evaluates sum of digits

Tags: python, debugging

I have just started beginning level of debugging. The task is finding and adjusting the faulty code of 2 functions: one evaluates the sum of odd digits, while the other does the even digits.

I have found what the issues are, but don't know what to do afterwards.

```
def sum_odd_digits(number):
dsum = 0
# only count odd digits
while number % 2 != 0:
    # add the last digit to the sum
    digit = number % 10
    dsum = dsum + digit
    # divide by 10 (rounded down) to remove the last digit
    number = number // 10
return dsum

def sum_even_digits(number):
m = 1 # the position of the next digit
dsum = 0 # the sum
while number % (10 ** m) != 0:
    # get the m:th digit
    digit = (number % (10 ** m)) // (10 ** (m - 1))
    # only add it if even:
    if digit % 2 == 0:
        dsum = dsum + digit
    m = m + 1
return dsum
```

For the sum_odd_digits function, it gives the wrong value if the odd digit comes before the even one (e.g. 129 only returns 9, not 10).
For the sum_even_digits function, an infinity loop exists, and I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When thinking about a problem like this it helps to clearly structure the steps.

1. Break down an integer into its respective digits
2. Determine if given digit is even/odd and sum if the conditions are correct

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem, the most expedient and efficient is to perform the summation during the loop.

```
def sum_odd(number):
    sum = 0
    while number != 0:
        digit = number % 10
        if digit % 2 != 0:
            sum += digit
        number = number // 10
    return sum
```

In addition, you can see that both methods are very similar, and the ability to change between even and odd summation is only related to the `digit % 2` operation. Code could be reduced to a single method with an additional boolean argument to flag whether to sum odd or even.

Answer (score 3):

```
def sum_odd_digits(number):
    dsum = 0

    while number > 0:
        # add the last digit to the sum if it is odd
        digit = number % 10
        if digit%2!=0: # implies odd digit
            dsum = dsum + digit
        # divide by 10 (rounded down) to remove the last digit
        number = number // 10
    return dsum

def sum_even_digits(number):
    dsum = 0

    while number > 0:
        # add the last digit to the sum if it is even
        digit = number % 10
        if digit%2==0:  # implies even digit
            dsum = dsum + digit
        # divide by 10 (rounded down) to remove the last digit
        number = number // 10
    return dsum
```

Comment: refer to the provided comments to understand the logic involved